Converting System.String to System.Guid
I'm currently having a bit of a problem trying to convert a string with guid behaviour inside my database to convert to an actual Guid in my application. I have tried a lot of things, which currently this is how I have my "User" setup:
[EntityTypeConfiguration(typeof(UserConfiguration))]
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
{

}

As you can see I am using a Guid as TKey. At the top of my class you can see the Table schema in which I simply want to use the standard AspNetUsers table. Which above that I am applying my EntityTypeConfiguration which looks like the following
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);  
        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasConversion
            (
                guid => guid.ToString(),
                str => Guid.Parse(str)
            );
    }
}

To demonstrate my usecase I'm using a endpoint called
[HttpPost]
[Route(SessionRoutes.ProcessLogin)]
public async Task<ActionResult<LoginResult>> ProcessLogin(string userName, string password, bool isPersist)
{
    try
    {
        LoginResult result = new();
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        if (_userSessionService.IsBrowserValid(_browserService, _deviceService, out errorMessage))
        {
            result = await _userSessionService.ProcessLogin(userName.Trim(), password, isPersist);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest($"Login error: {errorMessage}");
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
        return BadRequest(new { code = "MANAGEMENTAPI-LOGGEDINUSERVALIDATION-999 ", message = "Er is iets mis gegaan. Probeer het opnieuw. " + ex.Message });

 public async Task<LoginResult> ProcessLogin(string userName, string password, bool isPersist)
 {
     try
     {
         LoginResult result = new();
         User appUser = new();
         string clientName = ConfigHelper.ClientName(_configuration);
         if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["UrlReferrer"].ToString == null)
         {
             return await Task.FromResult(result);
         }

         string uname = (userName + "_" + clientName);

         appUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(uname);

         IdentityResult identityResult = await _passwordHelper.ValidateAsync(_userManager, appUser, password);

         if (identityResult.Succeeded && appUser != null)
         {
             Guid Id = appUser.Id;

             if (await _identityService.VerifyPasswordAsync(appUser, password))
             {
                 if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await _userManager.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(appUser) > 0)
                 {
                     await _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(appUser);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await _userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(appUser))
                 {
                     await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(appUser);
                 }
             }

             var status = await _signInManager.HandleSignInResultAsync(await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(appUser, password, true));
        
         }
         return await Task.FromResult(result);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
     }
 }
    }
}

in which I do the following for now
var appUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

After calling this function from the UserManager which is the Identity UserManager I get the following error back in Swagger:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method31(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in ManagementAPI.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
ManagementAPI.Controllers.UserSessionController: Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.

This is how I have my UserManager setup:
public class IdentityUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    private readonly IdentityContext _context;
    public IdentityUserManager(IUserStore<User> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<User>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<User>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<User>> logger, IdentityContext context)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {}
}


I have tried multiple options to convert the string inside my database to a valid guid.
To support my database claim I have a screenshot here:

What I really want in the end is to simply convert the full AspNetUser that has a string as id inside the database, to be converted to a whole object in my project using a Guid and using the IdentityUser. Though the bottleneck seems to be the fact that its a string and not a guid. Now you're probably thinking "why not change the database value for that column". Well I simply can't, we are refactoring our project and still using a database thats not fully supported with a Guid for Id but in the future it will, so if we have the new database I can simply remove the converter I currently have for example instead of having to rewrite all the code.
I hope there is someone that could help me figure this out, I know this is possible but for some reason I'm not getting it to work.
Thanks in advance!

Can you set for Id property exact type which is needed?  EF Core may decide to use Guid type mapping for this property.

What do you mean exactly? Because I do want it to map to a Guid at the end.

builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(128)

Doesn't work sadly.

Which SQL is generated? Looks like EF Core is trying to get String from DataReader, but column contains Guid.

How would I check the generated SQL?

Everything documented: Simple logging

To convert System.String to System.Guid, use Guid.TryParse(string, out Guid) or Guid.Parse(string). Both methods provide reliable conversions, essential for handling GUIDs within .NET applications.

Seeing that the OP is already using one of the options you mentioned, and the other doesn't seem relevant in this case, I'm not sure you fully understand the question.

^^ See conversion setup in second snippet in the question.

ChatGPT to the rescue.
